# Iterating Firebase children with non sequential id

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

```js
var data;
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref();
starCountRef.on("value",snap =>{
  data = snap.val();
  console.log(data);
  uid = //some uid here;
  checkifplaying(data,uid);
});
function checkifplaying(data,uid){
  var flag1 = 0;
  var pos = -1;
  console.log(data);
  data.Users.forEach(function(user){
    if(uid == user.uid){
      flag1 = 1;
      which = data.User;
    }
  });
  if(flag1 == 0){
    $("#contest3").show();
  }
  else if(flag1 == 1){
    $("#contest1").show();
    $("#contest2").show();
  }
}
```

My Firebase DB looks like this:

[image]

I am trying to iterate the Users children using forEach loop

```
data.Users.forEach(function(user){
})
```

, but it is giving an error as `data.Users.forEach is not a function`. data contains the whole of db which was taken through snapshot. 
And it contains the master object in it.

Please tell me how to iterate this.

Comment: Would you mind pasting some of the code?

Comment: @TylerBiscoe pasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the snapshot value to your function. You should pass the snapshot object instead. Like this:

```
starCountRef.on("value",snap =>{
  //data = snap;
  console.log(snap.val());
  uid = //some uid here;
  checkifplaying(snap,uid);
});
```

And on your checkifplaying function:

```
function checkifplaying(data,uid){
  var flag1 = 0;
  var pos = -1;
  console.log(data);
  data.child('Users').forEach(function(user){
    if(uid == user.uid){
      flag1 = 1;
      which = data.User;
    }
  });
  if(flag1 == 0){
    $("#contest3").show();
  }
  else if(flag1 == 1){
    $("#contest1").show();
    $("#contest2").show();
  }
```